# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spatial'

Tags: python, spatial, scipy-spatial, geoalchemy

I've been faced to Module Not Found Error in a script which all it's requirements has been installed. I'm trying to import spatial library:

```
import spatial
```

This library is located here:
**C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial**

I checked installed packages through `pip list` and it was okay. I tried to install spatial-lib in Pycharm project environment but it couldn't be done:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spatial-lib (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for spatial-lib
>   You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

It's nonesence, because my pip is up-to-date. Maybe good to say, importing **scipy** has such probelms too.

Comment: Check which version of python you are using. Also importing a module and printing its __file__ will print its site_packages directory.

Comment: The version is 3.7.1
I mentioned the directory, so what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like spatial is a sub-package of scipy. Therefore, to import spatial, you should use the following:

```
from scipy import spatial
```

Comment: Thanks. Beside this, I added geoAlchemy and other packages to project interpreter; it worked :)